# Why is iOS Simulator not running?

Tags: ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

When I try to run my program, iOS Simulator goes black and displays this error:

[image: Unable to boot the iOS Simulator]

`Unable to boot the iOS Simulator.`

When I click OK, Xcode shows this error:

[image: Unable to run app in Simulator. An error was encountered during running (Domain = NSMachErrorDomain, Code = -300)]

`Unable to run app in Simulator. An error was encountered while running (Domain = NSMachErrorDomain, Code = -300)`

How I can I make it run again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are running two different instances of the iOS Simulator.

1. Clean the project. (`CMD+SHIFT+K`)
2. Quit Xcode.
3. Quit all instances of iOS Simulator.
4. Restart the computer.
5. Log in.
6. Make sure no instances of iOS Simulator are running (I had a wrong version set to Open At Login)
7. Run your project, and let Xcode open the right Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently updated XCODE and possibly have more than one installation you may need to specify which XCode is being used via the command line.

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Reset Content and Settings worked for me. Also clean the project once and build.